# Will a for loop inside of a while loop fully complete its iterations before the while loop loops once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to use a for loop in a while loop, but the for loop only executes once. My goal is to make an array with the for loop, then check that array for repeating values using the while loop. I'm not too sure if this is just how javascript does loops, but I can't wrap my head around why that would be. When I run this code, I get an error stating that slotarr[1].value is undefined.

If it isn't possible to run a for loop in its entirety in a while loop, are there any workarounds?

```
var slotobj = {
  sloticon1 : {
    icon : ":bread:",
    value : 1
  },
  sloticon2 : {
    icon : ":custard:",
    value : 2
  }
}

  var slotarr = [];
  var done;
  var j = 0;
  var k = 8;
  while (done == false) {
    for (i = j; i <= k; i++) {
      slotarr[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
      if (slotarr[i] <= 50) {
        slotarr[i] = slotobj.sloticon1;
      }
      else if (slotarr[i] > 50 && slotarr[i] <= 100) {
        slotarr[i] = slotobj.sloticon2;
      }
      else {
        i--;
      }
    }
    if ((slotarr[0].value == slotarr[1].value) || (slotarr[0].value == slotarr[2].value) || (slotarr[1].value == slotarr[2].value)) {
      j = 0;
      k = 2;
    }
    else if ((slotarr[3].value == slotarr[4].value) || (slotarr[3].value == slotarr[5].value) || (slotarr[4].value == slotarr[5].value)) {
      j = 3;
      k = 5;
    }
    else if ((slotarr[6].value == slotarr[7].value) || (slotarr[6].value == slotarr[8].value) || (slotarr[7].value == slotarr[8].value)) {
      j = 6;
      k = 8;
    }
    else {
      done = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You haven’t initialized `done` to `false`, so `(done == false)` will never be true, so your `while` loop will never run. The error is likely telling you that `value` cannot be read from the undefined `slotarr[1]`, because it’s never being set. Letting the loop run currently results into an infinite loop (as far as I’ve tried it), so you’ll have to rethink your logic.

Comment: Probably need to set   `var done = false;` to make it explicit. That `i--;` looks suspect (I did not do deep analysis here) and feels like an infinite loop here.

Comment: And yes, loops work as you would expect them to.

Comment: Oh god I can't believe I didn't set done to false. Thank you guys!

Comment: Your loop still doesn’t make any sense. What is it supposed to do? There’s a very small chance it will stop. Now suppose any of the three lower `if` or `else if` cases is reached and executed. Please tell me: when exactly will it ever reach the `else` case which sets `done` to `true`? Almost never: suppose both `slotarr[3].value == slotarr[4].value` and `slotarr[0].value == slotarr[1].value` are `true`. So `j` will remain `0` and `k` will remain `2` _forever_. That results in an infinite loop.

Comment: By doing `for (i = j; i <= k; i++)` instead of `for (var i = j; i <= k; i++)` you make `i` global, probably not a great thing.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Then `let` should be used anyway.

Comment: Ahh, so basically the code given was a boiled down version of what I'm using to make a little slot machine game. I would create an array using the initial for loop. Then slotarr[0], slotarr[1], and slotarr[2] make up one column and so on. Using the first column as an example, I checked if 2 values were the same with the "if ((slotarr[0].value == slotarr[1].value)..." statement. If there were any matches between slotarr[0], [1], and [2], then the for loop would loop between 0 - 2. Once no columns have matching values, the while is done. I've tried the code and I haven't gotten an infinite loop.

Comment: Does your `slotobj` contain more than two `sloticon`s?

Comment: Yes, the slotobj has 8 in total, I just shortened it to 2 for the sake of simplicity for the question at hand.